# how to check in jquery if something not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried the following code to understand how i can get 0 if the value is not defined.

This below is my try to understand but I am getting same error as described below.

```
var tbl = $("#tableOccupation")[0] != 'undefined' ? $("#tableOccupation")[0] : 0;
alert(tbl.rows.length);
```

that if not undefined,

return `0` else return whatever the `rows.length` is

that is above my try but it is still showing

`Uncaught TypeError: tbl is undefined`

Comment: `const tbl = $("#tableOccupation");  console.log(tbl?.length ?? 0)`

Comment: Don't check for `undefined`, it's notoriously unreliable.  Check `$("#tblId").length === 0`.  See this answer for more details: [is there an exists function in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery).  But in many cases you don't need to:  `$("#tableOccupation tr").length` would give you what you want, 0 if there's no table and 0 if there's no rows in that table.

Comment: Does this answer your question (though not directly asked this way): [is there an exists function in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)?

Answer (score 0):

Your error come from this :

```
var tbl = $("#tableOccupation")[0] != 'undefined' ? $("#tableOccupation")[0] : 0;
```

You should check for `undefined` like this ( by removing quotes surrounding `undefined` )

```
var tbl = $("#tableOccupation")[0] != undefined ? $("#tableOccupation")[0] : 0;
```

`undefined` is a type, not a string :

```
console.log(undefined == 'undefined') // Prints false
```

More cleaner solution would be to just check for `undefined` like this :

```
let tbl = $("#tableOccupation")[0];

if (tbl) {
  alert(tbl.rows.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `rows` collection in a HTML Table element refers to every `tr` within that table, you can just do this:

```
let $tbl = $("#tableOccupation");
let numberOfRows = $tbl.find('tr').length;
console.log(numberOfRows);
```